# To install Brew's ImageMagick and fix its Symlink

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, graphics, image-processing

Assume you installed Imagemagick by

```
brew install imagemagick
```

but it does not get into your PATH. 
For example, I run unsuccessfully

```
compare
```

since imagemagick is not in PATH: `-bash: compare: command not found`.

The command `ls -l /usr/local/bin/compare` gives

```
ls: /usr/local/bin/compare: No such file or directory
```

My .bash_profile

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi

# http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53058/15504
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Echoing `$PATH` gives

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin
```

which seems to be ok because `/usr/local/bin/` there.

### ImageMagick in my system - answers to 4ae1e1's answer

The command `brew --prefix` gives `/usr/local` so ok.

The command `brew info imagemagick` gives

```
imagemagick: stable 6.9.0-3 (bottled), HEAD
http://www.imagemagick.org
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.0-3 (1440 files, 22M)
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: xz ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: libtool ✔, xz ✔
Recommended: jpeg ✔, libpng ✔, freetype ✔
Optional: fontconfig ✔, libtiff ✔, little-cms ✘, little-cms2 ✘, libwmf ✘, librsvg ✘, liblqr ✘, openexr ✘, ghostscript ✘, webp ✘, fftw ✘
==> Options
--enable-hdri
        Compile with HDRI support
--with-fftw
        Compile with FFTW support
--with-fontconfig
        Build with fontconfig support
--with-ghostscript
        Build with ghostscript support
--with-jp2
        Compile with Jpeg2000 support
--with-liblqr
        Build with liblqr support
--with-librsvg
        Build with librsvg support
--with-libtiff
        Build with libtiff support
--with-libwmf
        Build with libwmf support
--with-little-cms
        Build with little-cms support
--with-little-cms2
        Build with little-cms2 support
--with-openexr
        Build with openexr support
--with-perl
        enable build/install of PerlMagick
--with-quantum-depth-16
        Compile with a quantum depth of 16 bit
--with-quantum-depth-32
        Compile with a quantum depth of 32 bit
--with-quantum-depth-8
        Compile with a quantum depth of 8 bit
--with-webp
        Build with webp support
--with-x11
        Build with x11 support
--without-freetype
        Build without freetype support
--without-jpeg
        Build without jpeg support
--without-libpng
        Build without libpng support
--without-magick-plus-plus
        disable build/install of Magick++
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
```

which seems to be ok.

I run the command  `brew link imagemagick` and get

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.0-3... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/convert
Target /usr/local/bin/convert
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/convert'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite imagemagick

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run imagemagick
```

This seems to be strange. **How can you solve this problem?**

I run the command `brew reinstall imagemagick` and get

```
==> Reinstalling imagemagick
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/imagemagick
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/imagemagick-6.9.0-3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring imagemagick-6.9.0-3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/convert
Target /usr/local/bin/convert
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/convert'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite imagemagick

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run imagemagick

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/convert
/usr/local/share/man/man1/convert.1
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.0-3: 1440 files, 22M
```

so something wrong in symlinking.

**How can you solve the error about symlink?**

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Do you know how to use the command line?  Have you read the ImageMagick manual pages?  You haven't given us much in the question to work with, so it's hard to know how to help you.  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own before asking here, and to show us in the question what you've tried and what happened.

Comment: Basically you just run it from Terminal with the options you want. From your question it's unclear whether running from Terminal fails, whether you don't know how to use it to accomplish a specific task or whether you have a different problem. So please clarify by editing your question, it will then automatically placed into the reopen queue.

Comment: what does `type compare` return? and `ls -l /usr/local/bin/compare`?

Comment: Ahh, and which error message to you get on running `compare`?

Comment: Please try `type -a compare` and `ls -l /usr/local/bin/compare` as patrix suggested.

Comment: Okay, then `compare` is simply isn't there.

Comment: I'll give you a list of things to try shortly.

Comment: maybe it's a bit useless now, but this simple solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998161/osx-lion-cannot-remove-imagick

Comment: In my case it was way simpler to install it with "port"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A list of things to try, in order (I'm writing an answer instead of a comment for better formatting). Run `hash -r` after each step (assuming you're in bash; do `rehash` instead for zsh; or you can always open a new shell).

1. Run `brew --prefix` and see if the output is `/usr/local`. If not, your `brew` is not installed to `/usr/local`! Add `$(brew --prefix)/bin` to you `$PATH`.
2. Run `brew info imagemagick` and make sure it's actually installed; maybe you had an error during installation and it was simply not installed successfully.
3. Run `brew link imagemagick` to symlink to `/usr/local/bin`; maybe the executables weren't symlinked correctly (for some reason);
4. Run `brew reinstall imagemagick` to reinstall.
5. If it still doesn't work, show us the output of `brew list imagemagick` and we'll see what's wrong.

Comment: You are right! There is some error in symlinking. See my update.

Comment: I did *rm '/usr/local/bin/convert'* and *rm '/usr/local/share/man/man1/convert.1'*?

Comment: @Masi That's not the best thing to do. `convert` is an ImageMagick command, so I'd say it's safe to just do `brew link --overwrite imagemagick`. If you want to be overly cautious, you can do `brew link --overwrite --dry-run imagemagick` to have a look at the list of overwritten files first, but I'd say that's not necessary.

Comment: By the way, maybe you installed some non-Homebrew software that provided a `convert` binary in `/usr/local/bin`? Could you run `convert --version` to make sure it's actually the ImageMagick `convert`?

Comment: The convert --version was ImageMagick's command. I removed the two files and now successfully reinstalled the imagemagic. I now have *compare* in my command line. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Great, glad it helped.

Comment: What is the purpose of the command **hash -r**? I get nothing in running it. I always tend to run **reset** after each installation.

Comment: @Masi `hash -r` rehashes the list of commands known to the shell. It helps with autocomplete and stuff, so why not. `reset` has little to do with your shell environment, it just resets the terminal and helps with nothing but printing issues.

Comment: [Is there a way to link everything except what conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46391301/656912) I have a conflicting `compare` that I'd like to keep, but I need ImageMagick 's `convert`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius No, and since this use case is clearly unsupportable from brew's point of view, I don't think we'll add an option for it even you request it. However, you can always copy/move your `compare` elsewhere, `brew link imagemagick`, then move your `compare` back to where it is. Beware that imagemagick (by me, as it happens) is updated quite frequently, so it's probably more convenient if you install your `compare` elsewhere before Homebrew's bin directory, say ~/bin.

Comment: @4ae1e1: Or just let Brew link and then make a different link (say `xyzcompare` to the other `compare`. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

jjrr's proposal in the comments where you need to follow the instructions too

```
brew doctor
```