# To install Shotwell in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, image-processing, install

I install the first dependencies of Shotwell  successfully

```
brew install libGphoto2 vala libgee
```

Some discussion about this issue in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775106/54964) but the accepted answer is misleading, since it is about how to install `pyexiv2`, not `gexiv2`.

I run `./configure` and get

```
Detected libGPhoto 2.5.x - using 2.5-aware code path.
Configured.  Type 'make' to build, 'make install' to install.
```

I run `make` and get

```
Package gexiv2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gexiv2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gexiv2' found
...
```

My .bash_profile

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi

# http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53058/15504
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Echoing $PATH

```
/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin
```

**How can you install Shotwell in OSX Yosemite?**

**How can you install the dependency *gexiv2* in OSX Yosemite?**

Comment: The linked answer only shows how to install `pyxeiv2`, *not* `gexiv2`.

Comment: How is this going? Is there perhaps a brew formula for installing Shotwell now? :)

Comment: @Hubro Please, let us know when you know something is going to work. I have not noticed anything that works yet. You can of course try Alistair's package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of right now there is no `gexiv2` brew formula but I've created and submitted one which will hopefully get accepted soon. You can follow here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/37944

Beyond that there are various dependencies of shotwell that aren't easily available through brew, for example `rest` and `gudev` which don't appear to exist anywhere for OS X. I'll have a go at creating formulas for them depending on how the first one goes.

Comment: Excellent! Let's hope that will be soon.

Comment: any update on this? i got stuck at `meson.build:44:0: ERROR:  Dependency 'webkit2gtk-4.0' not found`

Comment: for the record i was able to install `meson gtk+3 libGphoto2 vala libgee  gexiv2` through brew